# Divide list items by height when list items surpass UL height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create slides from dynamic content. Basically what I am trying to do is lets say I have a `<ul>` which is 300x100. I float the the list items and when the list items surpass the height of the `<ul>`. I want to wrap those list items in a div so that I can have x number of list items divided by height.

I'm trying something like this but I don't know if I am going in the right direction or where to go from here.

CSS:

```
<style>
    ul {
        height: 100px;
        width: 300px;
    }

    ul li {
        float: left;
    }
</style
```

HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>ffgggfs</li>
        <li>sffsfsf</li>
        <li>jgjghjgfj</li>
        <li>trtretert</li>
        <li>ghhfhfhgf</li>
        <li>sdfsdfsdf</li>
        <li>fghjjh</li>
        <li>iuyuiy</li>
        <li>cvcvc</li>
        <li>hgjhjg</li>
        <li>tryryre</li>
        <li>kkhjkhjk</li>
        <li>sdfsdfsdf</li>
        <li>khjkhjk</li>
        <li>adfsfafsaf</li>
        <li>syuuyuyu</li>
        <li>sweeerre</li>
        <li>last</li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
var sumHeight = 0;


$('ul li').filter(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        pHeight = $this.parent().height();      // parent inner height

    sumHeight += $this.outerHeight(true);       // + block outer height

    return sumHeight < pHeight;
}).insertAfter('ul').wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand perfectly. Here's a try: You want to dynamically add items to a ul with javascript until you've reached a certain height of the container, then you want to add a second container and start filling it?

Comment: that about sums it up yes. When the ul height is filled with items(reaching the ul height) i want to start filling a new ul.

Comment: Just a style note, your '<ul>` tags weren't showing up in your first written statement because you have to put them between ` ` for them to be seen as code rather than HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've not given you exactly what you asked for but it can be modified as you see fit.

In this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/bh4n8/2/) I use divs instead of ul/li, and I think they can be styled in any way you want.

There is a holder div, into which are added holders for each of your individual divs.
By changing maxheight, you can control how many lines go into each of your "slides".

```
var maxheight = 100;
var divlistnum = 0;

$('.holder').append("<div class='" + "slidelist" + divlistnum + "'></div>");

$('#clickme').click(function(){
    $(".slidelist" + divlistnum ).append("<div class='littlelist'>Stuff to Add</div>");

    if( $(".slidelist" + divlistnum).height() > maxheight )
      {
       divlistnum = divlistnum + 1;
       $('.holder').append("<div class='" + "slidelist" + divlistnum + "'></div>");  
       }
});
```

Comment: thanks TimSPQR, i appreciate your help. I modified it a bit and i have a link to show you.                                                                                      http://jsfiddle.net/static48/q24GX/

Just looking for some feedback of where i could improve the code. The reason is the content is loaded server side. im  then using jquery to format that output into multiple divs and add it to a slide show. The height will not be fixed. it will be the height of the parent container which could change in different screen sizes. 
Thank you

Comment: I think it looks good. Your use of .each is very interesting, and useful. Are you going to pull the data with ajax, or by php code on the HTML page? In terms of the height, you can add a variable for "screen height" (measured by jQuery or javascript) or some variable * screen height.

Comment: i will be using php to get the data. im still on the fence with how i am doing it.im gonna work it on it a bit more see if i can improve it a bit. Im not crazy about how i am hiding the original div and appending the results to another div. i know i can do that part better.

Comment: Perhaps the way to go about it is to assume ajax, set up a hypothetical returned json array, then parse and distribute those data. Try to keep the length of the array "real". Do you have the array varialbles?